# Donut Caching Tutorials

Tags: asp.net, donut-caching

Can someone point out a couple of good quality tutorials/pages for donut caching?  Like everything else on the web, you can google a million things, but several of the articles I've found are a bit confusing.

I'm looking for

1. What is donut caching
2. When should you use it
3. How do you implement in ASP.net

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Donut caching is where you cache every thing on a page except a few dynamic regions.
So you cache the doughnut but not the hole.

You should use it when most of you page is static other than 1 changable section.

You should read [this](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2006/11/28/tip-trick-implement-donut-caching-with-the-asp-net-2-0-output-cache-substitution-feature.aspx) on implementation advice.

Comment: I've always thought the opposite: you cache the hole (or the jam, depending on the type of doughtnut :-) ) and use Substitution controls to change what's round the outside. It depends on your page layout and where the most expensive bit of your page (to build) is I suppose.

Comment: Thanks.  I think the initial explanation of the concept is what I was missing.  None of the articles (listed below) really start at the high level and drill down.  You start out neck deep in implementation and specific libraries.

Comment: @PhilPursglove, you're thinking of "Donut Hold Caching" :-P  
http://haacked.com/archive/2009/05/12/donut-hole-caching.aspx

Answer (score 3):

1. article by [Phil Haack](http://haacked.com/archive/2008/11/05/donut-caching-in-asp.net-mvc.aspx) (asp.net mvc)
2. article by ScottGu on [asp.net weblogs](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2006/11/28/tip-trick-implement-donut-caching-with-the-asp-net-2-0-output-cache-substitution-feature.aspx)
3. implementing donut caching on [wackylabs](http://www.wackylabs.net/2006/11/implement-donut-caching-with-the-aspnet-20-output-cache-substitution-feature/)

and all this with one [google search](http://www.google.com.sg/search?rlz=1C1_____enIN310IN310&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=donut+caching)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that you're going to get better results by using stackoverflow as a human powered search engine.  Honestly, anything that anyone here will post will be sourced from a search engine query such as this one:

http://www.bing.com/search?q=asp.net%20donut%20caching

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I'd go so far as to call it a *good* tutorial but if you watch [this video](http://video.nunney.me.uk/ddd7/This_One_Goes_Up_to_11_or_How_to_Write_Scalable_ASP.NET.wmv) there's a short demo of how to write donut caching at about 36 minutes in.

How to do it boils down to:
Add [output caching](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hdxfb6cy.aspx) to your pages.
Decide what items need injecting into your cached pages before they get returned to the client.
For each item, create a `static` (`Shared` in VB) method that returns the item e.g.

```
Public Shared Function LoginName(ByVal context As HttpContext) As String

    Return "Welcome, " & context.User.Identity.Name

End Function
```

Add a `Substition` control to your page in the appropriate location for each item, which calls the method you just created.

```
<asp:Substitution runat="server" ID="LoginNameSubstitution" MethodName="LoginName" />
```

And you're done!